# Food101 Tensorflow Dataset Requested split "validation" does not exist

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to use food101 dataset but while it has meta folder of train and test it can only see train data.

```
(train_data, test_data), ds_info = tfds.load(name="food101",
                                             split=["train", "validation"],
                                             shuffle_files=True,
                                             as_supervised=True,
                                             with_info=True)`
```

this is where I'm learning AI while his code works mine doesn't
https://github.com/mrdbourke/tensorflow-deep-learning/blob/main/07_food_vision_milestone_project_1.ipynb

the documentation for food101 says it has train and validation but I downloaded train and test in my folders

I'm using jupyter notebook
I don't know why it can't see it

I tried to change validation to test but it didn't work either

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.